# find geometry distance between rows x y z in pandas

Tags: pandas, geometry

I have such dataframe

```
               x          y             z
0      1202.3235  541.05555  2.835000e+01  
1      1202.3235  541.05555  2.835000e+01
```

It is necessary to find the rows, which have got very small distance from other rows.
Distance should be calculated by analythical geometry rules

```
np.sqrt((x1-x0)*(x1-x0)+(y1-y0)*(y1-y0)+(z1-z0)*(z1-z0))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You are more likely to get an answer if you describe the steps you have taken to try to solve the problem including the research you've done. See how to ask a good question on SO here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Grouping similar data points is normally done using cluster analysis.

You will find suitable methods in Scipy (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/cluster.html) or scikit-learn (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html) which can be applied directly on pandas dataframes.

For example, this code:

```
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import linkage, fcluster
tree = linkage(my_data, method='ward', metric='euclidean')
clusters = fcluster(tree, t=some_threshold, criterion='distance')
```

or this one:

```
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering
clusters = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=None, distance_threshold=some_threshold).fit(u).labels_
```

will group together the points below a threshold distance and the `clusters` variable will contain the cluster number assigned to each data point.